# Injection exception on servlet

Tags: java, servlets, hibernate-entitymanager

Successfully deploy to Glassfish. Go to run it and

```
com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class com.wellpoint.mobility.aggregation.admin.HomeServlet
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:329)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.createServletInstance(WebContainer.java:983)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.createServletInstance(WebModule.java:2130)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1404)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1211)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:237)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Env-Prop: com.wellpoint.mobility.aggregation.admin.FireboltServlet/entityManager@Field-Injectable Resource. Class name = com.wellpoint.mobility.aggregation.admin.FireboltServlet Field name=entityManager@java.lang.String@@@ into class com.wellpoint.mobility.aggregation.admin.FireboltServlet: Can not set javax.persistence.EntityManager field com.wellpoint.mobility.aggregation.admin.FireboltServlet.entityManager to com.wellpoint.mobility.aggregation.admin.HomeServlet
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:717)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:484)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:141)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:127)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:324)
... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.persistence.EntityManager field com.wellpoint.mobility.aggregation.admin.FireboltServlet.entityManager to com.wellpoint.mobility.aggregation.admin.HomeServlet
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:75)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:665)
... 34 more
```

FireboltServlet is our implementation of HttpServlet, all of our Servlets extend that class. It has a field entityManager

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistenceUnit", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
private EntityManager entityManager;

...

public EntityManager getEntityManager()
{
    if (entityManager == null)
    {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit");
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }
    return entityManager;
}

public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager)
{
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```

But I can't find anything attempting to map HomeServlet to that field, nor can I imagine why it would. This exception seems to have popped up out of nowhere, I haven't made any recent changes that I can imagine causing this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have a get and set of entity manager in the servlet?

Comment: FireboltServlet has a get and set for it. I included it in the post. HomeServlet makes no reference to the field.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the server freezes objects mainly the latter, as it does not recognize it, what I do is create a phantom method to lock and release that I need to compile and recognized.

That I do when I do not recognize some method.